# getting access to outlook exchange global address book

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, addressbook

i am building a csharp application and i would like a dropdown list of all users in my **outlook global address book** (the same one when i click on To: from outlook gui.  is this possible to get this progrmaticall?  what are the security requirements here?

Answer (score 2):

Security ramifications, in addition to the Outlook dependency left me unable to use this approach, in the past. As a result, I ended up building this in the form of an [LDAP query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol). Another plus is that, (in response to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811666/using-the-outlook-object-model-can-i-get-the-fields-that-i-see-in-the-outlook-co)) you will be able to extract contact information because this information is stored in the Active Directory.

**DISCLAIMER:** It has been almost five years since I have looked at this code, so I'm afraid I no longer fully understand the query. Hopefully it's enough to get you started, however.

```
DirectoryEntry adFolderObject = new DirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(adFolderObject);

adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
adSearcher.Filter = "(& (mailnickname=*) (| (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(homeMDB=*))(!(msExchHomeServerName=*)))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(homeMDB=*)(msExchHomeServerName=*))) ))";

foreach (SearchResult adObject in adSearcher.FindAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine("CN={0}, Path={1}", adObject.Properties["CN"][0], adObject.Path);
}
```